# SharePoint Designer 2007 - custom submit button committing every content type to default content type

Tags: sharepoint-2007

When I submit a new item to a list with 5 content types, everything is being saved as the default content type.

Applications:  SharePoint 2007 & SharePoint Designer 2007

I have a list with 5 content types.  I have created Custom List Forms for each one to replace the Newform.aspx page.

I have commented out the code for the default "Save" buttons on these forms because I want them to redirect the user to a page other than the default list view upon submittal.  I tried using the "Redirect URL" command on the default buttons, but it appears to have no effect on the functionality:

```
<SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="savebutton1" RedirectUrl="http://www.destinationpageforuser.com"/>
```

Then I did a little internet research and swapped out the default buttons for this chunk of code:

```
<input type="submit" value="OK" name="btnFormActionSave1" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={http://www.destinationpageforuser.com}')}" />
```

This allows the redirect to happen, but causes every new item to save as the default content type.

Then I tried adding a Form Action Button from the Toolbox in Designer:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit1" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={http://www.destinationpageforuser.com}')}" />
```

When I press this, it 1) causes the item to submit as the default content type, 2) clears the NewForm.aspx page of data, and 3) does not redirect but rather sits there on the now empty NewForm.aspx page blinking stupidly at me.

Do I need to pass the content type id somewhere in the button code to ensure the content type is correct?  I'm not experienced enough with coding to know where this might go.

So to sum up - I need to both redirect my users to a specific page upon submittal of a new item to the list, and I need the different content type to be respected.  Any insight would be appreciated.